# How to copy all files with .jpg extension to a new folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find all the pictures on my computer and copy them all to just 1 folder.  Here is the command I am using in Admin level Command Prompt.

C:>dir /s /b *.jpg | findstr /v .jpg > AllPics

For some reason I get this output: "Access is denied."

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the full path names of the JPG files in the current directory and all subdirectories:

```
dir /s /b *.jpg
```

Redirect the standard output stream of the `dir` command to the standard input stream of the `findstr` command. Exclude any file that contains `.jpg` (case sensitive) in the full path name:

```
| findstr /v .jpg
```

The result of the previous action seems to be counter-intuitive as it will negate a lot of output generated by the `dir` command.

Write the standard output stream of the `findstr` command to a file called `AllPics` (without a file extension) in the current directory:

```
> AllPics
```

<s>The current directory seems to be set to the root of the `C:` drive. Because administrator privileges are required to save files directly to the root of the `C:` drive, you'll receive the "Access is denied" error message.</s>

As pointed out by TripeHound, the "Access is denied" error might be caused because there already exists a folder named `AllPics` on the root of the `C:` drive.

One way to get the desired result is to parse each JPG file to the `xcopy` command:

```
setlocal
set "files=c:\*.jpg"
set "destDir=c:\AllPics"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir "%files%" /b /s') do (
  xcopy "%%f" "%destDir%\"
)
```

---

I've added another variant of the script that alters the destination name of the file to be copied which prevents potentially overwriting any possible duplicates.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "files=c:\*.jpg"
set "destDir=c:\AllPics"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir "%files%" /b /s') do (
  for %%d in ("%destDir%\%%~nf*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
  xcopy "%%f" "%destDir%\%%~nf!count!%%~xf*"
  set count=
)
```

---

Due to delayed expansion, the last variant of the script is unable to handle files that contain carets (`^`) within their fully qualified path name.

When a command-line contains environment variables that are expanded at execution time (like the `count` variable in this script), the entire command-line seems to be parsed twice. The for-loop variables (`%%f` and variants thereof) will be expanded during the first parse, the `count` variable is expanded during the second parse. Because the for-loop variables are already expanded when the second parse takes place, any singular carets present in the values of the for-loop variables are swallowed by the parser and omitted from the final result.

Here is the revision of the script that should take care of the problem described:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "type=.jpg"
set "source=c:\"
set "dest=c:\AllPics"

for /r "%source%" %%f in ("*%type%") do (
  for %%d in ("%dest%\%%~nf*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
  set "source=%%f"
  set "dest=%dest%\%%~nf"
  xcopy "!source!" "!dest!!count!%type%*"
  set count=
)
```

Comment: The OP says they used an admin-level command-prompt: my guess is the error was because `AllPics` already existed as a directory.

Comment: Good catch, it seems I've overlooked that. I also think that you're right about the reason of the error.

Comment: @treintje I tried the above and got this error: '%%f was unexpected at this time'.

Comment: The code was written to be stored and executed from a batch file. If you want to use a one-liner in CMD, you could use this: ``for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir c:\*.jpg /b /s')do xcopy "%f" c:\AllPics\``

Comment: Why does it ask me if I want to overwrite the pics in the AllPics folder if nothing is in there?

Comment: I have to hit y for every picture copied.

Comment: The script is trying to copy all the JPG files on your `C:` drive to the same folder: `C:\AllPics`. If two different files located in two different folders somewhere in your `C:` drive share the same name, the destination will be the same for both files and `xcopy` will prompt to have you confirm to overwrite the file that was already copied to the `AllPics` folder.

Comment: Is there another way to do this that does not require a overwrite for every duplicate?

Comment: You could suppress prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file with the `/y` switch of the `xcopy` command. But that does mean that only the last file found in case of duplicates will be stored in `AllPics`. (Not to mention the overhead when there are lots of duplicates.) Another way is to use `robocopy` instead of `xcopy` and specify the `/mir` switch to maintain the directory tree of the source files. Or you could check for the existence of the destination file and change the destination parameter accordingly before issuing the `xcopy` command.

Comment: I've edited my post and provided another way to overcome the additional problem that you're facing. If the destination file already exists, an incremental value will be added to the original file name to prevent overwriting any possible duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I do this with WinRAR. Archive files from different folders with recursive scan, then extract in one folder (with `e` option, not `x` which restores the directory tree).